# jQuery Ajax each() Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new with jQuery. I try to fetch some data using Ajax and I want to loop it and insert it inside `result` div.

The data not displayed in the `result` div.

```
var url = 'http://node.globalresearch.my/mybanjir/ws.BencanaJKR.php?function=getBencanaJKR&output=json&state_code=06';

var result_div = $('#result');

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (i, val) {
        result_div.append(val.id);
        });
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/w7jhaqz1/

Am I doing any mistake?

One more, how to access individual `id`? Say I want to only show `status` for `id` 1, how to do that?

Comment: @Alnitak The data not displayed in the result div.

Comment: When I try to open http://node.globalresearch.my/mybanjir/ws.BencanaJKR.php?function=getBencanaJKR&output=json&state_code=06 (which is the url you are trying to access in your AJAX request) in my browser all I get is an empty array. So I am not quite sure what exactly do you expect to get from an empty array. You might consider calling a server side script that returns some data.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I get the array: http://i.imgur.com/N5Itpdq.jpg

Comment: Hmm, you are right. A moment ago when I posted my comment the server was returning an empty array. The next thing you should ensure is that the server supports CORS if you want to be able to invoke it with AJAX otherwise the same origin policy restriction built into the browsers will simply prevent you from calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax` call.  The URL you are accessing - which, interestingly supports CORS - isn't sending the right `Content-type` header.

That header tells jQuery how to process the data.  It's not sending the correct header, so jQuery doesn't know to parse it as JSON.  Adding `dataType: 'json'` tells jQuery to assume it's JSON and parse it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d) {
        $.each(d, function (i, val) {
            result_div.append(val.id);
        });
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#loading").show();
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#loading").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've added dataType like you said. The result is still 'Loading...'

Comment: @zulhfreelancer: Works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w7jhaqz1/2/  UPDATE: I added a `<br/>` after each id to make it easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/w7jhaqz1/3/

Comment: Ok, thanks! One more, how to access individual id? Say I want to only show status for id 1, how to do that?

Comment: @zulhfreelancer: Just don't use a loop?  Try `d[1].id`?